# Label description for scikit-learn Diabetes dataset

Tags: scikit-learn, dataset, labels

I am studying how to build a regression model using the [Diabetes dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_diabetes.html) from scikit-learn and I cannot find a good interpretation for the target value, meaning that I do not know what value would be good for a patient or not. I read the [first article](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/LARS/LeastAngle_2002.pdf) where it was mentioned, but no information regarding the target value except that it is a quantitive measure. Does anybody has any clue?

Thank you!

Comment: this may be on purpose so as to avoid people taking medications based on the dataset values. In any case you dont need further explanation of the target variable, simply try to approximate it

Comment: Yes, but I'm working on a project where I need to explain the result obtained, if the disease of a patient will evolve good or not.